# PDF/A Conformance issue

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

So I've got my ItextSharp set up, and I've got the signing process to work to a degree, embedding images and fonts are working but I get the following validation error when I sign the document(Not certifying), "A string is longer than 65535 bytes." and this is causing my document not to conform to the PDF/A-1a standard. I've inspected the code and it seems the problem is lying in the MakeSignature.SignDetached method for ITextSharp(5.5.6) any particular reason that this would be occurring?

Signed Document with error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9RyqgJoa6W8Q1ZySkhjUS1iTmM/view?usp=sharing

```
private void SignDocumentSigningBlock(Certificate certificate, SigningInformation information, SigningBlock block, PdfSignatureAppearance appearance, PdfStamper stamper, byte[] signatureImage)
{
    X509Certificate2 x509Certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificate.Bytes, certificate.Password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    appearance.SetVisibleSignature(block.Name);
    SignDocumentSigningBlockWithImage(signatureImage, appearance);
    SignDocumentSigningBlockWithText(appearance, x509Certificate);

    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)x509Certificate.PrivateKey)
    {
        IExternalSignature externalSignature = new PrivateKeySignature(DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(rsa).Private, _settingManager["DocumentSigningEncryptionHashAlgorithm"]);
        MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, externalSignature, SignDocumentSigningBlockBuildChain(x509Certificate), null, null, new TSAClientBouncyCastle(_settingManager["DocumentSigningTimestampingServiceAddress"]), Int32.Parse(_settingManager["DocumentSigningEstimatedTimestampSize"]), CryptoStandard.CMS);
    }
}
```

Any advice or help would be appreciated.
Kind regards

**Update**

I've signed the document reducing the estimated size to 20400, but I still have the same warning when doing the compliance check.
Link to the new document: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9RyqgJoa6W8UkpGODhLWHl5bTQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MakeSignature.SignDetached` call

```
MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, externalSignature, SignDocumentSigningBlockBuildChain(x509Certificate), null, null, new TSAClientBouncyCastle(_settingManager["DocumentSigningTimestampingServiceAddress"]), Int32.Parse(_settingManager["DocumentSigningEstimatedTimestampSize"]), CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

explicitly asks iTextSharp to reserve space for

```
Int32.Parse(_settingManager["DocumentSigningEstimatedTimestampSize"])
```

many bytes to embed the signature.

Thus, please reduce the `_settingManager["DocumentSigningEstimatedTimestampSize"]` value.

A value of `0` asks iTextSharp to make a rough estimate. Such an estimate may exceed some limits and, therefore, should not be used in your case.

By the way, the name `DocumentSigningEstimatedTimestampSize` is misleading here.

**PS**: If you embed additional material like CRLs, OCSP responses, or time stamps into your signature, the signature size to expect grows. For PDF/A-1a conformance please put as little of such additional information into the signature as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the response :) so I've tried what you've suggested and reduced the estimated size that I pass through to MakeSignature.SignDetached but I'm getting the same error when I try to validate the PDF/A-1a compliance. At the moment the estimatedSize im passing though is 20400. Sorry if the code section "Int32.Parse(_settingManager["DocumentSigningEstimatedTimestampSize"])" was misleading :(

Kind regards

Comment: *At the moment the estimatedSize im passing though is 20400* - It actually looks like you are passing in **104000**.

Comment: That was the value I was passing through 104000 at first and tried the smaller value as suggested, I will try again maybe i missed something on my side. Kind regards

Comment: If you try again with 20400 and the warning comes again, please share that PDF, too, for inspection.

Comment: I've updated the original question with the link to the new document, I'm still getting the same warning after changing the estimated size to 20400. Kind regards

Comment: @user2699460 Your new sample document has **two** signatures, the first one dated 2015-10-26 generated with an estimated size of 104000 (about which the validator complains) and the second one dated 2015-10-28 generated with an estimated size of 20400 (which does not violate any size limits). Please make sure that the inputs of your tests are PDF/A-1a conform, your input here wasn't due to the old signature.

Comment: By the way, the text of you signature visualization is a bit misleading, you should use information from the signer certificate, not a CA certificate.

Comment: yeah the text in the box is a random certificate i generated used to test the text generation. I generated it in 2014 and i havent really changed it, but our certificates are provided by a class 4 certificate provider:) thank for the input i didn't event realize that i generated the other field with 104000. Thanks alot mkl :)